# Drop down selection populates sheet with data from another tab

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of tickers and data for them that I would like to populate onto a sheet depending on a drop down selection. If USA is chosen I want to list the stocks labeled USA in RAW onto the DATA sheet with the corresponding information. Below is an example of a basic sheet with the drop down and then based on the selection it would load the correct data from the RAW tab into DATA starting at row 3.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P59BNPF9iiVPABf6A2X791IFO8FNljXOUyIray5YbsY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula in cell `A3`

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:D11," select A, B, C where D=UPPER('"&A1&"') ",0), 
           "Pick the country")
```

[image]

Please pay attention to the syntax

- `'"&A1&"'` will intercept the formula and pick the value from cell `A1`
- `UPPER('"&A1&"')` will turn the text in `A1` to upper case, making sure that any of `USA` or `Usa` or `Canada` or even `caNaDA` is returned.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Upon pasting that into the spreadsheet it asks for me to turn on iterative calculations. When I turn that on(set to 100 if thats enough?) it then populates the drop down with "pick a country" and then upon doing so nothing happens. I have made it so you should be able to edit the spreadsheet linked above if that helps at all. I turned iterative off again for now.

Comment: @marikamitsos, I believe you intended something like                                                           QUERY('Raw Data'!A2:D11," select A, B, C where UPPER(D)=UPPER('"&A1&"') "          Having UPPER on the A1 cell is probably not needed, since that list will be from a data validation list.  Having UPPER(D) is what will find uSA or cAnADa iin the data fields, right?  My apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @arkad, I think marikamitsos intended that formula for A3, not A1, since that is what the  image above shows - the green cell.  A1, the orange cell, should be your dropdown list value, specifying a single country...

Comment: ah how foolish of me TY!

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry about the mess. Thank you @kirkg13. It is now fixed.